# Android Studio - freeze before splash on startup

Tags: linux, android-studio

Latest Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1. OS: LMDE 6 Faye (based on Debian Stable). CPU: 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13700, RAM: 32 GB DDR5, Disk: SSD/M.2

Initially, there was no such problem. Android Studio startup + load cached project was approx 1 second. But now, I'm getting 2-3 seconds lag + desktop freeze before Android Studio splash is shown. Except monitor (2 monitors now) + additional hard disks attached, nothing changed.

There's nothing interesting in console output when starting android studio. Do you have any ideas what could cause that? Other apps work fast without any startup lag, so it must be some Android Studio issue.